# Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x} $

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x} $ and $ \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x} $

It looked simple at 1st sight but is not actually.  I will show 3 ways in which I proceeded to solve it.

**1st attempt:**

I used binomial expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ which gave

$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}\kern10.0pt\frac{1}{x}\left(1\kern10.0pt+\kern10.0pt\left( \frac{1}{2}\right. \right) \left( -e^{-x^2}\right) \kern10.0pt-\left( \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \times \frac{1}{2}}{1\times 2}\right) \left( -e^{-x^2}\right) ^2+\kern10.0pt\left( \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{2}}{1\times 2\times 3}\right) \left( -e^{-x^2}\right) ^3.....\left. \right) $

Now if assume that $-e^{-x^2}$ can be safely assumed 0 under the limit then it will give an infinite series 1-1/2-1/8-1/16-5/128....
Now I don't know how to check whether a series converges or not. If I assume that it converges, then there are 2 possibilities which is that it converges to 0 or
a non-zero value. In case it converges to a non-zero value then if it is positive then the RHL asked in the question will be +infinite and LHL will be
-infinite. In case it is negative, then the answers for RHL and LHL are reversed. But if they converges to 0 then it would mean that the assumption that $-e^{-x^2}$ can be taken as 1 will be wrong.

**2nd Attempt**

In this case I thought about applying L'Hospital rule to the previous step. Again if I assume that $-e^{-x^2}$ can be safely assumed 0 under the limit then it will give 2x(1/2 +2/8 + 3/16 + 4 × 5/128....) where x tends to 0. Now in case this infinite series converges to a finite value, then the answers to both the questions will be 0. But if it converges to +/-infinity, then our assumption was again wrong. We can again apply L'Hospital rule and repeat the same process till we get some computable series.

**3rd attempt**

This time I first directly  applied L'Hospital rule to my question (without any expansion) and got $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}} e^{-x^2} $
This time I was confident that I can assume that $e^{-x^2}$ can be safely assumed 0 under the limit. Now the result was quite surprising for me. It is $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}  $ which is just the reciprocal of my question. Suppose that the answer to my question is y then this implied that the reciprocal of the expression will also tend to y. So basically if I divide these 2 equations, then I will get y²= 1 which meant that either y=1 or y= -1. Note that it is still possible that the RHL and LHL could be different(one of them is 1 and the other is -1). Now the question was which of these 2 possibilities will be correct for both RHL and LHL.

I noticed one thing. The expression $\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x} $ is an odd function meaning that LHL and RHL must be additive inverses of each other. Further I also saw that the term inside square root must be positive and so expression will have same sign. This meant that the RHL must be 1 and LHL must be -1.

While I was happy at that, I took me one more hour to realise that I had done a blunder. I will illustrate this with an example:

Consider a function $ g(x)= signum\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) $

Now suppose I ask you to find LHL and RHL of g(x) as x tends to 0. Your answer will be an oscillating number. But suppose I ask you that find g²(x) as x tends to 0. You will find that in this case both LHL and RHL will be one(I think so.) Even if it is not 1, I still believe that the prediction I made from the fact that y²= 1 would imply y= +/- 1 is a blunder since there could be exceptions.

Finally to check my answer, I searched the graph on desmos. Here I can clearly see that my 3rd attempt was correct https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ntforxcviv

So, in conclusion my question is

1. how can I solve the question using the 1st and 2nd attempt, in other words how can I solve that infinite series.
2. Why did the 3rd attempt worked even if there were chances of failure? Is it possible to know wether using this method in some other problem would be fruitful or not?
3. Still, the 3rd attempt was my own method and therefore I still don't believe such a method could be accepted by someone else(for example, my friend). So, is there any genuine method of solving it using the commonly used rules(factorisation, cancellation of common terms, expansion and L'Hospital rule)?

**EDIT:**

I assumed that  $ \lim_{x \to 0} signum^2\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) $ will be 1 because it seemed highly intuitive to me at that time. But not now. I think there is very small possibility of it being 0, but a good possibility of it being an oscillating number from 0 to 1. I don't know a rigorous method to solve it. What should be the answer?

Comment: I believe this limit does not exist, since the numerator is always positive and the denominator may not be...

Comment: The expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ is useful for $x$ near $0$, but $-e^{-x^2}$ is near $-1$ when $x \approx 0^+$.

Comment: @abiessu The denominator is positive since $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: @Gary: I believe that the title limit is expanded into the body limits as a way to indicate that the limit result can be determined without significant calculation...

Comment: @abiessu definitely, since RHL is +1 and LHL is -1

Comment: The question is unclear: are you looking for the limit in the title, or the two limits in the body of the question?

Comment: @robjohn my main  query was that in the title but it has been resolved. So the question in the body is a remaining query and I have asked it separately here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4501019/1066603

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the power series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ consider the expansion of $e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+O(x^6)$. So the limit is
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)}=1$$

Similarly we can see that the limit as $x$ approaches $0^-$ is $-1$ so the limit does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Hint: start by considering
$$\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}\ .$$

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$e^{f(x)}-1\,\,\sim\,\, f(x)$$
When $f(x)\to 0$ and $x\to x_0$. So:
$$1-e^{-x^2}\,\,\sim\,\, x^2$$
Then, the limit became:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x}\,\,\sim\,\,\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|x|}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{x}=1$$