# Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} signum^2\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) $

Tags: limits

This question came in my mind while I was writing this question:

[Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}{x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496994/1066603)

$ \lim_{x \to 0}\operatorname{signum}^2\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) $

While writing that question I thought that the answer to this question should be 1 and I was quite confident about that but my confidence slowly decreased. My argument why it may or may not be 0 is as follows:

Think about the graph of sin(1/x) it oscillates at any number between -1 and 1 including both at x=0. If it is not zero, then the answers of my question will be definitely 1. Suppose it is 0. Now we will check its derivative. If the derivative is not 0 then the answers to my question is 1 but unfortunately it itself is a number oscillating from -infinite to +infinite. And so on goes for higher order derivatives. This leaves a very slight possibility ( my intuition says it is least probable) that the answer could be 0, but there is a slight chance that the answer itself be a number oscillating at 0 and 1. I don't know of any genuine method to solve such kind of questions.

Comment: **The limit doesn't exist** as the map is equal to zero for a sequence converging to zero and is equal to one for another map converging to zero.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net so basically you are saying that it itself is an oscillating number at 0 and 1. Atleast can we say that limit supremum is 1 and limit infimum is 0?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: So can I say that atleast $ \lim_{x \to 0}$ modulus of ($\operatorname{signum}^2\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) - 0.5 $) will be 0.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what @mathcounterexamples.net said, the limit does not exist. We can see this by considering specific sequences approaching 0 that give rise to different limits.

For example, take $x_n = \frac{1}{n \pi}$. Then $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but $\sin \left( \frac{1}{x_n} \right) = \sin \left( n \pi \right) = 0$ for all $n$. (Think of this as the points where the graph crosses the $x$-axis amidst the ever-increasing oscillations near 0.)

On the other hand, take $x_n = \frac{2}{(4n-3) \pi}$. Then $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, too, but $\sin \left( \frac{1}{x_n} \right) = \sin \left( \frac{(4n-3) \pi}{2} \right) = 1$ for all $n$. (Think of this as the points along the peaks of the ever-increasing oscillations near 0.)

Similarly, you could find sequences that approach 0, but the images of the points would approach any given number between 0 and 1. So it's not so much that 'the number is oscillating at 0 and 1,' as much as 'there is no single number.'

Comment: So can I say that atleast $ \lim_{x \to 0}$ modulus of ($\operatorname{signum}^2\left( \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right.) \right.) - 0.5 $) will be 0.5 ?